# How to create a Windows Phone Live Tile in the style of the People Hub

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to create a windows phone live tile in the style of the people Hub in windows phone home screen

Comment: In what way of that style? Where it's comprised of 9+ images that keep changing as you look at it?

Comment: yeah exactly i wanna do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. You have some control over the live tile, but the level of control that the people tile has is not something a 3rd party Windows Phone application can do.